# Can't use custom build annotation in Android Library Module

Tags: java, android, android-library

I am trying to build an Android Library for existing Java Library. In my Java library there is annotation called `org.wso2.siddhi.annotation.Extension`
When I try to add this annotation to a class I get the following error.

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':siddhiservice:transformClassesAndResourcesWithSyncLibJarsForDebug'.
> java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: META-INF/annotations/org.wso2.siddhi.annotation.Extension
```

This is my class implementation.

```
package org.wso2.siddhiservice.sensors.proximity;

import org.wso2.siddhi.annotation.Example;
import org.wso2.siddhi.annotation.Extension;

@Extension(
        name = "proximity",
        namespace="source",
        description = "Get events from the proximity sensor",
        examples = @Example(description = "TBD",syntax = "TBD")
)
public class ProximitySensorSource extends Source {
}
```

If I just remove the @extension and clean the project it works fine. Problem happens only when I add the annotation.These are my libraries.

[image]

What is the solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

use `annotationProcessor` in application `gradle.build` file

```
    implementation files ('libs/Siddhi.jar');
    annotationProcessor files ('libs/Siddhi.jar')
```

Also, use `{ transitive = false }` to avoid duplicate files

```
implementation (group: 'org.wso2.extension.siddhi.io.tcp', name: 'siddhi-io-tcp', version: '2.0.15'){ transitive = false }
```

It works for me

[image]